# How to find lost userform control

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with a bunch of frames. I accidentally dropped a checkbox into one of those frames and it is now nowhere to be found. It still exists, because I'm able to set the value of it with the code, but I can't see it. I tried expanding the frame and also moving the things in the frame (in case it went behind one of those controls). How can I pull it back out?

Comment: If you press Ctrl+A can you see the outline of all the controls?

Comment: Ha! Ctrl+A revealed it. It had become tucked up above the top of the frame. Oddly, I had tried stretching the frame in every direction, but I guess it had become anchored up there. 

FWIW, the `Top`/`Left` parameter change also worked (when I relost it to try) 

Thanks!

Comment: @DukeSilver - added an alternative approach to find the **parent control** hiding your *'lost child'* including a `TypeName` filter resulting in a structured info list in your immediate window. Could help for future search as well as documentation purposes :-)

Comment: @DukeSilver - could you give my solution a try? Would appreciate your feed back if you found my approach helpful as it offers a structured and extended info list.

Answer (score 3):

This will tell you the position of the checkbox within the frame:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Debug.Print Me.CheckBox1.Left
Debug.Print Me.CheckBox1.Top

End Sub
```

After that, it's merely a question of expanding the frame in that direction and grabbing the "runaway child".

Answer (score 1):

**Find wanted controls with parent names and positions**

You could use this example code to locate systematically any types of controls:

```
Sub AnalyzeCtrls()
' Purpose: Analyze Userform controls
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
   Debug.Print "Control                  Parent                          Position" & _
               vbNewLine & String(76, "-")
   For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls          ' << change to your userform name
     ' display only "Checkbox" data               ' << change to wanted search type
       If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then Debug.Print ctrlInfo(ctrl)
   Next ctrl
End Sub
```

**Helper function**

```
Private Function ctrlInfo(ctrl As MSForms.Control) As String
' Purpose: helper function returning userform control information
     ctrlInfo = _
         Left(TypeName(ctrl) & _
         ": " & ctrl.Name & String(20, " "), 20) & vbTab & _
         " .." & IIf(TypeName(ctrl.Parent) = "UserForm", "Me    " & String(15, " "), _
                     Left(TypeName(ctrl.Parent) & ": " & String(10, " "), 10) & _
                           Left(ctrl.Parent.Caption & String(15, " "), 15)) & vbTab & _
         " Top " & Format(ctrl.Top, "# 000") & "/ Left " & Format(ctrl.Left, "# 000")
End Function
```

**Example result in immediate window**

```
Control                  Parent                          Position
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CheckBox: CheckBox1      ..UserForm1:MyForm              Top  006/ Left  570
```

Displaying the parent control helps you to find your *lost* control(s) there, e.g. a Frame, Multipage page or the userform itself.