# Unhide button in UserForm on vba developing window

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an Excel spreadsheet that was created by someone else. The file contains a `UserForm` and on that `UserForm` there is a **text field** and also a **CommandButton1**.

[image]

As you can see the **CommandButton1** is hidden on the `UserForm`. As far as I could evaluate the hiding of the the **CommandButton1** is probably done by setting the `top`, `left`, `height` and `width` property to `0`.

My question is now how can I get the `properties` of this **CommandButton1** so I can change them back and make the button unhidden again. Is there a setting of the vba developing window I need to change so it displays me all the tools that are used in the UserForm?

Currently, my developing window looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Right click on the userform and click to properties or click to F4 ;)

Comment: You can list the controls' properties - cf. (How to find lost userform control)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862861/how-to-find-lost-userform-control/50863522#50863522]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the element you would like to modify on the dropdown (all elements of your form should be visible there):

[image]

If you cannot locate Properties window then go to View/Properties:

[image]

Comment: Hi Pawel, I cannot find the dropdown in my developer window (see edits on my question). How can I add this window?

Comment: Go to View/Properties Window. I have edited answer with additional print screen.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.